# Halacha to be jew (from parents)

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

I have a friend that her grandfather (from her mother) was jew, he married a woman that wasn't jew.

What is the halachic position of this friend of mine??? Is she considered to be jew? If not, what is her situation if she desire to make aliyah/conversion?

Comment: Your last question involves the secular *Law of Return* which has nothing to do with the halachic definition (under which your friend is definitely not Jewish). Aliyah would be allowed (as a non-Jew) because of the secular law. A number of Russians have emigrated to Israel with this status. Conversion is an halachic matter and your friend would be treated like any other non-Jew that wanted to convert.

Answer (score 0):

The property of being a Jew is inherited from the mother.  Since her mother's mother was not Jewish, her mother is not Jewish, and therefore she is not Jewish.

(The reform movement takes a different view of the question but on this site the defining position is the orthodox view.)

Comment: Answers from a reform position [are allowed](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1307/1569), but sources are expected as always for answers of any perspective